# How to extract specific text after certain pattern

Tags: regex

I have a sample text `8 Pair 20+22AWG (7x28) Bare Copper, aDIN PVC DIN`

I need to extract specific keywords `AWG` and `DIN` given that they are **not** preceeded or **followed** by alphapets

I tried this expression `[^a-zA-Z]+AWG|DIN` but it also extracts  `20+22` how can I limit the expression to exact keywords ?

Comment: Should only `AWG` also match?

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes, only the keywords should match if they are not preceeded or followed by alphabets

Answer (score 1):

You may use a negative lookahead and you need to fix the regex by adding a grouping construct around the values you want to extract:

```
(?<![a-zA-Z])(?:AWG|DIN)(?![a-zA-Z])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NcWFCL/3)

**Details**

- `(?<![a-zA-Z])` - no letter allowed immediately on the left
- `(?:AWG|DIN)` - either `AWG` or `DIN` letter sequences
- `(?![a-zA-Z])` - no letter allowed immediately on the right.

Comment: Thanks, but I need same case on the right side too i.e.  `AWGd` doesn't match but `AWG-` matchs

Comment: @Exorcismus `\b(?:AWG|DIN)\b`? `(?<![a-zA-Z])(?:AWG|DIN)(?![a-zA-Z])`?

Answer (score 1):

You are currently matching 1+ chars other than a-zA-Z followed by matching `AWG` OR you match only `DIN`.

You could make the distinction using a capturing group `(AWG|DIN)`

If lookarounds are not supported, you could use the capturing group with your negated character class (without the quantifier `+` as you only need to verify a single char).

```
(?:[^a-zA-Z]|^)(AWG|DIN)(?:[^a-zA-Z]|$)
```

- `(?:[^a-zA-Z]|^)` Match any char other then a-zA-Z or start of string
- `(AWG|DIN)` Capture in **group 1** either `AWG` or `DIN`
- `(?:[^a-zA-Z]|$)` Match any char other then a-zA-Z or end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IHq7JQ/1)